# Is there any better way to display POST request in Angular Js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have used both `PUT` and `POST` request to modify and create a data. But the thing is `POST` request is not working properly. When i click on `add()` button , automatically `POST` request is generating id in the json-data before filling the information in the text fields.

Moreover data should be updated when I click on the `save()` button . Below I have pasted my code, if I have made any mistake tel me know and I appreciate every one whomever gives any information.

HTMl :

```
<button class="btn btn-info" ng-click="addmode()"> Add </button> 
<button class="btn btn-success" ng-show="editMode" ng-click="saveinfo()"> Save </button>
```

Angular JS :

```
$scope.addmode = function(information) {
    var postinfo = information;
    $http({
        url:'http://localhost:3000/contacts' , 
        method : 'POST',
        data : postinfo
    })
    .then(
        function successCallback(response) {
            $scope.selectedcontact = '';
            console.log(response.data)
        },
        function errorCallback(response) {
            console.log("Error : " + response.data);
        });    
    };
```

Comment: The call to addmode in your ng-click does not provide any data, as they are expected in the function definition. Maybe fix this first, and tell us, whats happening.

Comment: i passed the **information** parameter  in the `addmode()`. But empty object id is getting created

Answer (score 0):

**First create services/api.js**

```
angular.module('app')
    .factory('api', function ($rootScope,ApiEndpoint, $http, $q,$timeout,$cookies) {


        var get = function (url) {
            var config = {url: url, method: ApiEndpoint.Methods.GET};
            return this.call(config);
        };

        var del = function (url) {
            var config = {url: url, method: ApiEndpoint.Methods.DELETE};
            return this.call(config);
        };

        var post = function (url, data) {
            var config = {url: url, method: ApiEndpoint.Methods.POST, data: data};
            return this.call(config);
        };

        var put = function (url, data) {
            var config = {url: url, method: ApiEndpoint.Methods.PUT, data: data};
            return this.call(config);
        };

        return {call: call, get: get, post: post, del: del, put: put};
    });
```

**After create service/apiendpoint.js**

```
angular.module('app')
    .constant('ApiEndpoint', {
        ServerUrl:  'http://localhost/',
        BaseUrl: 'http://localhost/',
        Methods: {GET: 'GET', POST: 'POST', PUT: 'PUT', DELETE: 'DELETE'},
        Models: {
            test:"fe_api/test",


},
        URLS: {
            QUERY: 'app/'
        },
        getUrl: function (url) {

            var host=window.location.host;
            var protocol=window.location.protocol ;
            return protocol+"//"+host+"/"+url;

        }
    });
```

**Create model handler **

```
angular.module('app')
    .factory('ApiService', function (api, ApiEndpoint) {

        var getModel = function (url_part)
        {
            var url = ApiEndpoint.getUrl(ApiEndpoint.URLS.QUERY) + url_part;
            return api.get(url);
        };

         var getModelViaPost = function (url_part, data)
        {
            var url = ApiEndpoint.getUrl(ApiEndpoint.URLS.QUERY) + url_part;
            return api.post(url, data);
        };

        var postModel = function(model_name, data) {
            var url = ApiEndpoint.getUrl(ApiEndpoint.URLS.QUERY) + model_name;
            return api.post(url, data);
        };

        var putModel = function(model_name, data) {
            var url = ApiEndpoint.getUrl(ApiEndpoint.URLS.QUERY) + model_name;
            return api.put(url, data);
        };

        var deleteModel = function(model_name, id) {
            var url = ApiEndpoint.getUrl(ApiEndpoint.URLS.QUERY) + model_name + '/' + id;
            return api.delete(url);
        };



        return {
            getModel: getModel,
            postModel : postModel,
            putModel : putModel,
            deleteModel : deleteModel,
            getModelViaPost : getModelViaPost
        };

    });
```

**write API call in the controller**

```
var data = {
            wut_token: $cookies.data,
        };
        ApiService.postModel(ApiEndpoint.Models.test, data).then(function (response) {
            if (response.SUCCESS == "FALSE") {

            } else {


            }
        })
```

Comment: Above code boost your angular start up project and API call's